# File Transfer Server upload images just outside folder

Tags: html

I have a new web space from the host I use to work with, and it works perfect, but I have a problem with the images displayed:

This is my index.html code:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      Image in folder
      <img alt="Smiley face" src="folder/img1.PNG"></img>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      Image outside folder
      <img alt="Smiley face" src="img2.PNG"></img>
   </body>
</html>
```

The image inside the folder is not displayed.

I use *WS_FTP*, and inside public folder I have:

```
- index.html
- img2.PNG  
- folder (inside this I have img1.PNG)
```

Any ideas? I use to create web pages and this is the first time this happens to me.

Thanks

Comment: See again all links of img,spelling of folder name and images name.I think it should work.

Comment: Any errors in the `console`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder pesmissions in your server, maybe your site can not access to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

In the WS_FTP I had the radio button of ASCII files selected, instead of binary. I changed, upload again the images and it works!!